# How to import projection from a file in gdalwarp?

Tags: python, gdalwarp

I want to batch clipping and transforming rasters by a shp file. It looks like the projection file importing is wrong:

```
import subprocess
import os
import gdal,osr

inshape = r'D:\NorthGrass\Map\NorthTemperateGrass2.shp'
inpath = r'D:\GIMMS'
outpath = r'D:\NorthGrass\GIMMS82_132'

inproj = r'D:\NorthGrass\Map\GCS_WGS_1984.prj'
outproj = r'D:\NorthGrass\Map\WGS_1984_Albers.prj'

sr_proj = osr.SpatialReference()
sr_proj.ImportFromWkt(inproj)
tr_proj = osr.SpatialReference()
tr_proj.ImportFromWkt(outproj)

for filename in os.listdir(inpath):
     if os.path.splitext(filename)[1] == '.tif':

          inraster = os.path.join(inpath,filename)
          print filename+'   begin processing'

          outraster=os.path.join(outpath,filename)

          subprocess.call(['gdalwarp','-s_srs',sr_proj,'-t_srs',tr_proj,'-cutline',inshape, '-of', 'GTiff',\
                 '-crop_to_cutline','-tr','8000','8000','-ot','Int16',\
                 '-dstnodata','-32768',inraster, outraster])
          print outraster+'   is done'
print ' ----All Done----'
```

Hint error:

```
TypeError: argument of type 'SpatialReference' is not iterable
```

Comment: First, you need to open ***prj** file.

Comment: Your **sr_proj** and **tr_proj** objects are voids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to open ***prj** file to get projection. Next short code summarize the process for one of my shapefiles.

```
from osgeo import gdal,osr

sr_proj = osr.SpatialReference()

f = open('/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/polygon8.prj', 'r')

inproj = f.read()

sr_proj.ImportFromWkt(inproj)

print sr_proj
```

After running the code at the Python Console of QGIS, it was printed projection in WKT format:

```
PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 12N",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-111],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["Easting",EAST],
    AXIS["Northing",NORTH],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","32612"]]
```